# my code doesn't recognize `import sklearn`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install `scikit-learn`. I installed `numpy` and `scipy`, and I installed using both `pip install -U scikit-learn` and `conda install scikit-learn` (just to be sure).

However, once my code gets to a line like `from sklearn import datasets` - it throws an error:

```
 File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash 
(sklearn\utils\murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

My code doesn't seem to recognize `sklearn`, although I know it is installed; the only solutions I found on the web recommended on installing `scipy` - which I already have.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `conda` installed, a workaround would be creating a new environment. For example:

```
conda create -n my_new_env python=3.5
```

Choose the right Python version for you.

Activate the environment.

On Windows:

```
activate my_new_env
```

On Linux/Mac OS X:

```
source activate my_new_env
```

Now:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

and start a new Python interpreter in this environment.